# Como puedo resolver este error : "error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'."

Tags: angular8, primeng

En el service al mandar  llamar un json me arroja un error con el campo data.
"error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'."
Estoy usando el ejemplo de las tablas de primeng, pero me aparece el error anterior en esta linea **then(res =>  res.data)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { organizacion } from 
"../components/organizaciones/organizaciones.component";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { 
}
getData() {
return this.http.get("assets/data.json")
.toPromise()
.then(res => <organizacion[]> res.data)
.then(data => { return data; });
} 
}
```

Este es mi json:

```
{
    "data" :[
        {"brand": "Volkswagen", "year": 2012, "color": "White", "vin": "dsad231ff"},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345"},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr"},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh"},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "White", "vin": "hrtwy34"},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj"},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr"},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "White", "vin": "greg34"},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5"},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias leer el data del json, de esta manera:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { organizacion } from 
"../components/organizaciones/organizaciones.component";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { 
}
getData() {
return this.http.get("assets/data.json")
.toPromise()
.then(res => <organizacion[]> res['data'])    // <--------------
.then(data => { return data; });
```

} 
}

Comment: Muchas gracias :3